# Seeking Home Server Datatbase Environment to run SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I need to put together a personal database (run off my home computer) to analyze baseball/football records and statistics.

I want to use SQL.  At work I use **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** and I want a similar type of UI and Syntax to run queries on my baseball statistics at home.

I am hoping for free or 'cheap' option for the server, database, etc. Not a trial version.

I installed WAMP and am wondering if I am missing a piece of the puzzle to run queries what I have at work.

The problem I have is in writing and executing queries. Phpmyadmin won't let me run queries on the data. Do I need another program? Can you recommend another program to use?

I would love it if that program would execute T-SQL.

End goal, I am looking for a Database in which I'd be:
-- Importing a ton of CSV files, probably 10-20 GB worth
-- SQL/T-SQL Syntax (doesn't require PHP, etc)
-- I have Windows 7, 64-bit system.

What do I need to install to be able to run queries?

Thanks!

Comment: [SQL Server Express is free](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio at home.
MS SQL Express is a free software, you can install it at home for free.
Please note that there are some limitations in MSSQL Express edition, such as 10 Gb per database max, 1G of RAM max, 1 CPU core max
your 20 gigs of csv files will be transformed into 200 Mb inside of the database )))

Comment: Andrew, Aaron - thank you. It worked very well. I'm having a problem importing data into pre-created tables - but I'll scout around for the error code given. But it meets everything I asked for: t-sql, free, friendly UI, etc. Thank you!